# Use Task as dictionary key?

Tags: c#, dictionary, task, task-parallel-library

Is it okay to use `Task` as dictionary key or is that a bad idea? Any problems which might occur because of that?

Comment: Could this be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tasks don't have they own `GetHashCode` and are reference types derived directly from `Object`. As result `GetHashCode`/`Equals` does not vary based on state of the object and just depend on object's reference ([GetHashCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)).

As result `Task` can be used as key for dictionary and will allow to do fast lookup from a task to data. The matches will be on exact objects.

Common usage - associate some data with running tasks by code that runs them, i.e. logging ID:

```
 Task task1 = Task.Delay(100);
 Task[] allTasks = new[]{task1}; 

 var dictionary = new Dictionary<Task, string> { {task1, "first-task"}};

 Task completed = await Task.WhenAny(allTasks);
 Console.WriteLine($"Task {dictionary[completed]} finished");
```

Comment: In .Net Framework 4.8, this code snippet (a DoWork method returning Task, not Task<T> etc) will throw an exception on a duplicate key when the task is used as a dictionary key. It does not happen if the 'DoWork' method returns a Task<int> with different int values, but does if it always returns '1' for example. Must be cached tasks? (My code snippet is too long for a comment.. oh well).